# How to take reference from other files in flutter other than main.dart

Tags: android, xcode, flutter, dart

I have main.dart, search.dart, explore.dart as files in the flutter program. My search.dart and explore.dart are coded completely, but my main.dart is empty. What should be my main.dart 's code so than I have to import search and explore and have the app working ????

THIS IS MY main.dart CODE

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'search.dart';

```
void main(){
  //a class from myLib in the LibraryFile.dart file
  var some = new MyApp();
}
```

I imported search.dart file but when I run the app I only get a white screen

Comment: How have you created the project? By default, main is not empty. Maybe, this https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab#step-1-create-the-starter-flutter-app will help you!

Comment: please show what you have. Its too less information to give a meaningful answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the file you want to show first to your main.dart file and you can navigate to that page using the code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './search.dart';
import './explore.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Search(); 
      //home can be any screen you want. Search() or Explore(). 
      //With this part of code, your app will show the file you want.
    );
  }
}
```